# Is there a way to keep direction priorities in A*? (ie. Generating the same path as breadth-first)

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding, a-star

I have an application that would benefit from using A*; however, for legacy reasons, I *need* it to continue generating **exactly** the same paths it did before when there are multiple best-paths to choose from.

For example, consider this maze

```
...X
FX.S
....

S = start
F = finish
X = wall
. = empty space
```

with direction-priorities **Up; Right; Down; Left**.  Using breadth-first, we will find the path DLLLU; however, using A* we immediately go left, and end up finding the path LULLD.

I've tried making sure to always expand in the correct direction when breaking ties; and overwriting the `PreviousNode` pointers when moving from a more important direction, but neither works in that example.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think the behavior you are describing is related to the *heuristic* A* uses. In your case - I assume euclidean/manhattan distance. Note that if for example you set `h(v) in [0,1]` - A* will behave exactly like BFS, except the last step..

Comment: @amit: I know how to make it *behave* like BFS, but that's completely useless to me.  I'd like it to *behave* like A\* _(not lose the speed benefits)_, but generate the same path as BFS.  I've gotten it to work in 99.9% of the cases, but the above case fails.  Is there really no way to get the same path in the above maze?

Comment: I suspect it can be done by adding weights to the edges, such that `w(u,v) = 1 + f(u)*prio(u,v)` such that: (1) the total of additions to all edges combined does not exceed 1. (2) `f(u)` is calculated based on the distance (heuristic maybe?) from the source, and is monotonically decreasing, such that each f(u) is "more important" then all the nodes that will follow it in shortest a path to the target [probably will have the zeno property and decay exponentially]. However I cannot think of a way to prove it works, and also suspect it still might misses some details.

Comment: the submission deadline passed already! ;o)

Comment: @andrewcooke:  ...Sorry, what?

Comment: oh, sorry - this looks very like the ICFP 2012 competition, which was this weekend.

Comment: @andrewcooke:  Well, good that means someone probably figured out how to solve my problem :P do you know of a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with two ways of doing this.  Both require continuing the algorithm while the top of the queue has distance-to-start g-value <= g(end-node).  Since the heuristic used in A* is [admissable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), this guarantees that every node that belongs to *some* best-path will eventually be expanded.

---

The first method is, when we come to a conflict *(ie. we find two nodes with the same f-value that could potentially both be the parent of some node along the best-path)*, we resolve it by backtracking to the first point along the path that they meet *(we can do this easily in `O(path-length)`)*.  We then simply check the direction priorities of both paths, and go with whichever path would have the higher priority in a BFS-search.

---

The second method only works for grids where each node touches the horizonally- and vertically- (and possibly diagonally-) adjacent nodes *(ie. 4-connected grid-graphs)*.  We do the same thing as before, but instead of backtracking to resolve a conflict, we compare the nodes along the paths from the start, and find the first place they differ.  The first place they differ will be the same critical node as before, from which we can check direction-priorities.

We do this by storing the best path so far for each node.  Normally this would be cumbersome, but since we have a 4-connected graph, we can do this pretty efficiently by storing each direction taken along the path.  This will take only 2-bits per node.  Thus, we can essentially encode the path using integers - with 32-bit registers we can compare 16 nodes at a time; 32 nodes with 64-bit registers; and 64(!) nodes at a time with 128-bit registers (like the SSE registers in x86 and x64 processors), making this search very inexpensive even for paths with 100's of nodes.

---

I implemented both of these, along with @generic human's algorithm, to test the speed.  On a 50x50 grid with 400 towers,

- @generic human's algorithm ran about 120% slower than normal A*
- my backtracking algorithm ran about 55% slower than normal A*
- The integer-encoding algorithm only ran less than 10% slower than A*

Thus, since my application uses 4-connected graphs, it seems the integer-encoding algorithm is best for me.

---

I've copied an email I wrote to a professor [here](http://www.blueraja.com/files/pathfinding%20proof.txt).  It includes more detailed descriptions of the algorithms, along with sketches of proofs that they work.

Answer (score 5):

If the original algorithm was BFS, you are looking for the smallest of the shortest paths where "smallest" is according to the lexicographic order induced by some total order `Ord` on the edges (and of course "shortest" is according to path length).

The idea of tweaking weights suggested by amit is a natural one, but I don't think it is very practical because the weights would need to have a number of bits comparable to the length of a path to avoid discarding information, which would make the algorithm orders of magnitude slower.

Thankfully this can still be done with two simple and inexpensive modifications to A*:

1. Once we reach the goal, instead of returning an arbitrary shortest path to the goal, we should continue visiting nodes until the path length increases, so that we visit all nodes that belong to a shortest path.
2. When reconstructing the path, we build the set of nodes that contribute to the shortest paths. This set has a DAG structure when considering all shortest path edges, and it is now easy to find the lexicography smallest path from `start` to `goal` in this DAG, which is the desired solution.

Schematically, classic A* is:

```
path_length = infinity for every node
path_length[start] = 0

while score(goal) > minimal score of unvisited nodes:
    x := any unvisited node with minimal score
    mark x as visited
    for y in unvisited neighbors of x:
        path_length_through_x = path_length[x] + d(x,y)
        if path_length[y] > path_length_through_x:
            path_length[y] = path_length_through_x
            ancestor[y] = x

return [..., ancestor[ancestor[goal]], ancestor[goal], goal]
```

where `score(x)` stands for `path_length[x] + heuristic(x, goal)`.

We simply turn the strict `while` loop inequality into a non-strict one and add a path reconstruction phase:

```
path_length = infinity for every node
path_length[start] = 0

while score(goal) >= minimal score of unvisited nodes:
    x := any unvisited node with minimal score
    mark x as visited
    for y in unvisited neighbors of x:
        path_length_through_x = path_length[x] + d(x,y)
        if path_length[y] > path_length_through_x:
            path_length[y] = path_length_through_x

optimal_nodes = [goal]
for every x in optimal_nodes:  // note: we dynamically add nodes in the loop
    for y in neighbors of x not in optimal_nodes:
        if path_length[x] == path_length[y] + d(x,y):
            add y to optimal_nodes

path = [start]
x = start
while x != goal:
    z = undefined
    for y in neighbors of x that are in optimal_nodes:
        if path_length[y] == path_length[x] + d(x,y):
            z = y if (x,y) is smaller than (x,z) according to Ord
    x = z
    append x to path

return path
```

Warning: to quote Knuth, I have only proven it correct, not tried it.

As for the performance impact, it should be minimal: the search loop only visits nodes with a score that is 1 unit higher than classic A*, and the reconstruction phase is quasi-linear in the number of nodes that belong to a shortest path.  The impact is smaller if, as you imply, there is only one shortest path in most cases. You can even optimize for this special case e.g. by remembering an `ancestor` node as in the classic case, which you set to a special error value when there is more than one ancestor (that is, when `path_length[y] == path_length_through_x`). Once the search loop is over, you attempt to retrieve a path through `ancestor` as in classic A*; you only need to execute the full path reconstruction if an error value was encountered when building the path.

Comment: I'm not sure regarding this solution. It will still not return all paths (otherwise we get a contradiction to the fact that A* runs polynomial with the number of edges and vertices, since there are exponential number of paths). Can you provide explanation/proof guideline to show why we do not "lose" the prefered paths with this approach?

Comment: Thank you!  I've come up with a completely different solution myself *(involving backtracking when you have a potentially-conflicting PreviousNode value)* - I was waiting to post it until I've tested its speed vs. BFS, but I will add your solution to my test as well.  Thank you!!

Comment: @amit:  I'm fairly certain this will work.  This solution is essentially, find all nodes we *know* belong to a best-path, then walk from the start to the finish using our direction priorities, considering *only* those nodes and always going up in g-value.  The number of best-paths may be exponential in `n`, but the number of nodes belonging to a best path are linear.

Comment: Exactly. The DAG we construct contains *all* shortest paths (so there is an exponential number of them), but the DAG itself is a subset of the original graph so it is linear-sized. And we don't build an exhaustive list of every shortest path: we only have to manipulate each edge a bounded number of times to find the lexicographically smallest path.

Comment: I've discovered better ways to do this *(see below)*, but I'll give you the bounty since you were the only one besides myself to come up with a method to solve the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i would build in the preference on the path order directly into the heuristic function

i would look at the bread-first algorithm first

define a function for every path that the bread-first algorithm chooses:

consider we are running a depth-first algorithm, and it's at n-th depth
the previously done decisions by the algo: x_i \in {U,R,D,L}
assign U=0,R=1,D=2,L=3

then define:

```
g(x_1,..,x_n) = sum_{i=1}^n x_i * (1/4)^i
```

let's fix this step's g value as g'
at every step when the algorithm visites a more deeper node than this one, the g() function would be greater.

at every future step when on of {1..n} x_i is changed, it will be greater hence it's true that the g function always raises while running depth-first.

note:if the depth-first algorithm is successfull, it selects the path with the minimal g() value

note: g() < 1 beacuse max(L,R,U,D)=3

adding g to the A*'s heuristic function won't interfere with the shortest path length because min edge length>=1

the first solution an A* modified like this would found would be the one that the depth-first would find

for you example:

```
h_bread=g(DLLLU) = (23330)_4 * c
h_astar=g(LULLD) = (30332)_4 * c
```

()_4 is base4
c is a constant (4^{-5})

for you example: h_bread < h_astar

Comment: +1 this is nearly the same as one of the solutions I've already come up with *(haven't posted them yet)*, with the caveat it would probably be more efficient to keep the g-value and the encoding of the full-path-thus-far separate.  Also, it's important to note that this solution only works for grid-graphs with 4 (or 8) directions per node, while general BFS/Djikstra's and A* are much more widely applicable.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post this approach doesn't work if your path can grow very long. If two paths coincide for the first 30 steps, their g-value will be equal when represented as a `double` floating-point variable. So you have no way to know which path is lexicographically smallest.

Comment: base 4 can be replaced with max vertex connection, and floating point can be elimited with secondary level comparison logic

Comment: @ZoltánNagy: Sure, but that means that if your paths can have 3000 steps in the worst case, you need to store the path weights in at least 100 machine words. So in that case your algorithm becomes 100x slower than standard A\*!

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no non-trivial way to do this:

Breadth-first search finds the shortest path of lowest order determined by the order in which vertices are considered. And this order must **take precedence** over any other factor when breaking ties between paths of equal length.

Example: If the nodes are considered in the order A, B, C, then `Node A < Node C`. Thus if there is a tie between a shortest path beginning with A and one beginning with C, the one with A will found.

On the other hand, A* search will find the shortest path of lowest order determined by the heuristic value of the node. Thus the heuristic must take into account the lowest lexicographic path to each node. And the only way to find that is BFS.

Comment: *"And the only way to find that is BFS."* - Where does this statement come from?  Is that a guess?  I don't see why we shouldn't be able to keep track of/calculate the lexigraphic order somehow while running A*.

Comment: It's because the heuristic is a function of a particular node. It cannot depend on external factors like "what direction am I coming from?". So to calculate the heuristic, you will end up having to run a BFS. My intuition is that BFS is the optimal algorithm for this step. Sorry if this explanation is a little unclear. I will try and post a formal proof at a later date (rather busy right now :P).